BuildAction = None for all files
Requirement is we need to keep files in a project & not to include those files in the dacpac. When I set manually BuildAction = None. file not including in dacpac.This works.
But we have multiple files & many resources works on same project file everyday.
So created a folder and placed all files under that folder & edited .csproject as below
    <Project> 
    <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="dbo\TestFolder\*.sql" />
    </ItemGroup>
    </Project>

This too works. The actual problem comes when new file (say testing.sql) added to that folder, buildaction will be Build when i close and reopen solution, then Buildaction for the new file get set to "None". But that new file is still getting added in dacpac even when Buildaction = None. When I checked .csproject file
it looks like below
   <Project>
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
   <None Include="dbo\TestFolder\*.sql" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
   <Build Include="dbo\TestFolder\testing.sql" />
   </ItemGroup>
   </Project>

How do I make sure when new file added under "TestFolder" folder is always set to "None" and getting added in dacpac without MANUAL intervention?


If new ItemGroups appear and I delete them manually, will the BuildAction of the new .sql files in the folder be changed to None?

Am I correct that you mean not "just some files" but files written for testing the original project? And test files must not be included into the project dacpac so they don't appear on prod server after release, right?
